# IBM System x3250 M2: this HD is ok for this server?

Tags: ibm

I have an IBM IBM System x3250 M2.

The guide say http://www-07.ibm.com/systems/includes/content/x/pdf/xso03039usen.pdf

> All models offer impressive scalability, including up to 8GB of memory and a choice of high- performance hard disk drives with an internal storage capacity of 600GB (two 3.5-inch hot-swap SAS), 587.2GB (four 2.5-inch hot-swap SAS), or 1.5TB (two 3.5-inch hot-swap or simple- swap Serial ATA II).

Now I have 2 HD with 500 GB each, in Raid1.
The guide say that the maximum capacity is 1.5 TB.

But I need more space.

The only way for have more space is to mount 2 HD of 750 GB each ? Is correct ?

If yes, this model is good for this server ?

WD WD7500AZEX
http://www.wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=1093&language=1

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

well. that depends, are the current disks SATA or SAS ? 
are they 2.5" (laptop form factor) or 3.5" (desktop form factor)?

the model you described with 750GB is of the SATA desktop type, and can be used with your server only if it supports SATA disks currently.

also how are you planning to move the existing data on the 500GB RAID1 volume to the new ones?

to answer your question, the disk will work with this server, but if you're looking for performance , try looking for faster drives with 10000rpm or higher rotational speed

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now my configuration is in SATA 3.5". For the file there isn't a problem because I can copy in another pc and after re-copy on the server. I don't remember if the HD that now are mounted are 7200 or 10k. Now I'm search another 750 GB SATA 3.5" but with 10k RPM =D